# Python args and kwargs arguments confusion

Tags: python

I've been reading a bit about kwargs and args, but I'm really struggling how to implement them in this case.

I have an object of a class

```
a = MDFile()
```

which has a method

```
a.create_matrix()
```

which will return an n by m matrix where n is the number of particles in the MDFile. If the user does not specify any arguments to the method, I want it to return the full n by m matrix. But if the user specifies a particle number - say they only want the information for the 5th particle, I want them to be able to do:

```
a.create_matrix(particle_id=5)
```

and it will return the corresponding row of the matrix only, which will then be a 1xm array.

How can I achieve this using kwargs and args? Or is there a better, alternative, method for doing this? It seems args requires some kind of default value, which I don't really want. I also don't really want the method scattered with if statements because it slows down the performance quite badly.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `def create_matrix(self, particle_id=None)` then testing for `if particle_id is not None:`?

Comment: I can do that, but then I have an if statement in the method. That of course is an option, but I wanted to avoid that since I'll be using this method on millions of files which impacts on performance quite hard.

Comment: Well, if you want to vary behaviour based on arguments you will **have** to use an if statement.

Comment: I think you are optimizing prematurely here; performance is impacted more by repeated statements (loops) than one `if` statement that alters what your method returns.

Comment: I somewhat doubt that `if` statements are going to bottleneck performance, but... You may think about reworking your API.  How about `a.get_particle(5).create_matrix()`, where `get_particle` returns some sort of `Particle` object? etc

Comment: If adding an if to a function will decrease performance, you'll need to rewrite this function using a compiled language, or at least use Cython.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @Martijn Pieters is right. You will have to use an `if` statement, and frankly the `if` statement won't have too much effect. For example, consider the following tests:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('create_matrix(particle_id=None)', setup='def create_matrix(particle_id=None):\n    if particle_id:\t        return particle_id\n    else: return None', number=10000000)
1.3292641180877212  # if statement with particle_id defaulting to None
>>> timeit('create_matrix(particle_id=5)', setup='def create_matrix(particle_id=None):\n    if particle_id:\t        return particle_id\n    else: return None', number=10000000)
1.5606957465069584  # if statement with particle_id defaulting to 5
>>> timeit('create_matrix(particle_id=5)', setup='def create_matrix(particle_id=None): return None', number=10000000)
1.2185165279484238  # no if statement
```

On 10 million iterations, the `if` statement adds relatively little time. The last test excludes an `if` statement.

So you might try this instead (as @Martijn Pieters suggests):

```
def create_matrix(self, particle_id=None):
    if particle_id is not None:
        ...
```

Comment: `if particle_id:` seems to be a bad suggestion, as I guess one can expect `particle_id` to be equal to `0`, which will coerce to boolean `False`. I'd propose explicit `if particle_id is not None`. As a wise man said, explicit is better than implicit ;)